# Android Back key cycling focus instead of returning to previous activity

Tags: android, listview, back, searchview

I have this layout

[image]

Two SearchView widgets
One ListView

When I press the android back key the focus cycles between the filter box and the search box.
I want to go back to my previous activity, but I cannot do it, since the back key only goes from one box to the other.
How can I get the back key press event ?

this code does not even get called

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    super.onBackPressed();   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is definitely with the SearchView widgets and its handling of the focus/backkey.
I changed the SearchViews to EditTexts
I changed the QueryTextListeners to TextWatchers
and... voila!

Now the onBackPressed() is called and the activity can return to its previous caller.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can override activity's onBackPressed() method to do whatever job you wanna do on back key pressed like

you can call previous activity on back key press...like,

```
@override
public void onBackPressed ()
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, PreviousActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();

}
```

Comment: onBackPressed is never called.

Answer (score 0):

I always had trouble with the `onBackPressed`. You should try to use `onKeyDown` or `onKeyUp`.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // do something on back.
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Tried it, onKeyDown is not called, onKeyUp is not called. ::: If I had to guess it is as if the SearchView widgets are stealing the focus and do not bother to call their super routine.

Comment: Have you tried dispatchKey... I think that one is called before it is send to a child.

Comment: @Yes, I tried it ::: The problem is definitely with the SearchView widget, I am changing to EditText and TextWatchers